# How to remove spaces between elements in a list?

Tags: html, css

I would like to remove the spaces between the elements in the list. I can do this if I put the entire list in-line, but that makes things extremely hard to read.

This is what I have, I would like them flush against eachother.

[image: a]

```
<div id="navBar">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/" class="home">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="/">ROOMS</a></li>
            <!-- <ul>
                <li>Test</li>
            </ul> -->
        <li><a href="/profiles/" class="end">PROFILES</a></li>
    </ul>

       <!-- stuff -->
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#navBar {
display: inline-block;
height: 30px;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border-top: 3px ridge #292929;
}

#navBar ul{
display: inline;
list-style: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0; 
font: 15px bold Arial;
background: transparent;
}

#navBar ul li {
padding: 0;
display: inline;
text-align: center; 

}

#navBar ul li a{
display: inline-block;
width: 110px;
height: 23px;
padding-top: 7px;
text-decoration: none;
color: White;
border-right: 1px groove #292929;
border-bottom: 1px groove #292929;
background-color: #70797F;
}
```

I think that's about it that pertains to this part of the page.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use "float: left" instead of "display: inline"

check this http://jsfiddle.net/ckzmF/

```
#navBar ul li {
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  float:left;
  /* display: inline; */
}
```

Comment: All good answers, but you noticed the unneeded inline that I would have missed. Thank you.

Comment: When you apply float it makes the element inline, so you don't need to set inline.  It's implied.

Answer (score 2):

Float your `li` to the left.

```
#navBar ul li {
    padding: 0;
    display: inline;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/senoramor/762MK/)

Answer (score 2):

With the float property you can remove the space between elements.
[check this](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp)

```
#navBar ul li 
{
padding: 0;
display: inline;
text-align: center;
float:left;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also set margin-left or padding-left to -2px (or any other number that suits)